# Using JQ to delete blocks from CloudFormation.template.json

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, jq

I'm using jq (on bash) to delete blocks from json templates. I'm currently deleting 50% of what I want, by using the "Type" element from CloudFormation templates :

`jq '(del(.Resources | .[] | select(.Type=="AWS::CodePipeline::Pipeline")))' $fileName > newTemplate1.json`

I Would also need to delete every resources that contains "cdkpipelinePipeline", before the Type block :

```
  { "developcdkpipelinePipeline": {
      "Type": "AWS::CodePipeline::Pipeline",
      "Properties": {
        "RoleArn": {
          "Fn::GetAtt": [
            "developcdkpipelinePipelineRole",
            "Arn"
          ]
        }
    }
  },

    "developcdkpipelinePipelineRole": {
      "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
      "Properties": {
        "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
          "Statement": [
            {
              "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Principal": {
                "Service": "codepipeline.amazonaws.com"
              }
            }
          ],
          "Version": "2012-10-17"
        },
        "Tags": [
          {
            "Key": "Application",
            "Value": "develop"
          }
        ]
      },
      "DependsOn": [
        "AuroraNestedStackAuroraNestedStackResource"
      ],
      "Metadata": {
        "aws:cdk:path": "develop-cicd-stack/develop-cdkpipeline/Pipeline/Role/Resource"
      }
    }
  }, 
...
```

Do you have any clue on how to achieve that ? I Basically want thoses two blocks to be removed from my template.

Thank you already

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following jq fragment in your pipeline:

```
with_entries( select(.key|contains("cdkpipelinePipeline")|not) )
```